# ISNULL for two SELECT queries instead one scalar value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, isnull

I would like to do something like this:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL_QUERY((SELECT TOP 1 A.Id, A.Value FROM A), (SELECT TOP 1 B.Id, B.Value FROM B))
```

It should return a row with Id and Value columns e.g:

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TestValue |

I would like to not run two of these select queries and then choose one, because they are too "heavy" for that.

I can't use:

```sql
    SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 1 [Id], 'test' [Value]), (SELECT TOP 1 2 [Id], 'test2' [Value]))
```

Because there will be an error:

Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

and I would like to get two columns not one

Comment: So, apart from that isn't just `ISNULL` not `ISNULL_QUERY`, what isn't working about your attempt?

Comment: Is this part of a larger `select` or just these four values? And what do you do if `A.Id` is not null but `A.value` is?

Comment: These selects are examples only, in reality they are freaking large but resulting only four values too. Both Id and Value will be nulls in the same time, it is guaranteed. I can change them to return no rows instead of nulls, but problem still will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work if SQL Server materialized CTEs:

```
WITH a as (
      SELECT TOP (1) A.Id, A.Value
      FROM A
     )
SELECT id, value
FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (1) b.id, b.value
FROM b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a);
```

But it doesn't.  If you really need to control the execution (and cannot trust the optimizer), then you might need to use temporary tables:

```
 SELECT TOP (1) A.Id, A.Value
 INTO #A;
 FROM A;
```

And then:

```
SELECT id, value
FROM #A
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (1) b.id, b.value
FROM b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #A);
```

Or even:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #A)
    SELECT id, value
    FROM #A
ELSE
    SELECT TOP (1) id, value
    FROM B;
```

Comment: I was thinking about CTE too (it would be ideal for me), but like you said sql server doesn't do such thing that I want with it and your idea with temp table and exists is the closest solution I could think of. I would rather not doing it with temp table but without a better ideas I have to accept it :(

Answer (score 0):

Use a set based approach to do so, with the UNION operator like this :

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.Id, A.Value FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 B.Id, B.Value FROM B 
WHERE NOT EXIST(SELECT TOP 1 A.Id, A.Value FROM A)
```

**Complementary tests....**

0 - intial settings

```
CREATE TABLE T_A (CA INT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE T_B (CB INT PRIMARY KEY);

SET STATISTICS IO ON;
-- rewrited query :
WITH
T1 AS (SELECT TOP 1 CA FROM T_A ORDER BY CA),
T2 AS (SELECT TOP 1 CB FROM T_B ORDER BY CB)
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T1);
```

1 - all tables are filled

```
INSERT INTO T_A VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO T_B VALUES (9), (8), (7);
```

*Table 'T_A'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4
Table 'T_B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2*

table T_A read twice

2 - B empty, A filled

```
DELETE FROM T_B;
```

*Table 'T_A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2
Table 'T_B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2*

All table read once

3 - A empty , B filled

```
INSERT INTO T_B VALUES (9), (8), (7);
DELETE FROM T_A;
```

*Table 'T_A'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4
Table 'T_B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2*

Table A read twice.

Now with the two tables filled with 1,000,000 rows

```
DELETE FROM T_A;
WITH 
TN AS (SELECT 0 AS I
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT I + 1 FROM TN
       WHERE  I < 9)
INSERT INTO T_A
SELECT T1.I + 10*T2.I + 100*T3.I + 1000*T4.I + 10000*T5.I + 100000*T6.I
FROM   TN AS T1
       CROSS JOIN TN AS T2
       CROSS JOIN TN AS T3
       CROSS JOIN TN AS T4
       CROSS JOIN TN AS T5
       CROSS JOIN TN AS T6;
DELETE FROM T_B;
INSERT INTO T_B
SELECT * FROM T_A;
```

4 - Two table filled with 1 million rows

*Table 'T_A'. Scan count 2, logical reads 8
Table 'T_B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3*

5 - table A empty, table B 1 million rows

*Table 'T_A'. Scan count 2, logical reads 6
Table 'T_B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3*

6 - table B empty, table A 1 million rows

*Table 'T_B'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3
Table 'T_A'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3*

The conclusion is : no matter if twice access (scan count), because only few pages will be reads...

Comment: It runs two times SELECT FROM A so it is the reason why I would like to find other approach.

Comment: How could you say that ? Do you have make some tests ? Do you have check the execution plan ? Do you have read the IO stats ? Do you understand how the SQL engine will work in such a case ? I have add some more example to my answer to ley you understand...